# CoreLocation database includes a mysterious Executable key resulting in an `Application not found at the expected path` warning

Tags: macos

I've run into an interaction with my macOS app and CoreLocation that I can't quite figure out.

On a small number of macs (managed by a third party - the customer) the entry in the CoreLocation clients.db plist includes an "Executable" key that points to an invalid location for my app.

The result is a yellow "yield" icon in System Preferences/Security & Privacy with a tool tip stating `Application not found at the expected path (...)`. If permission was granted within the application, this entry will persist. However, if the user unchecks the permission box, the entry disappears and will never return.

Interestingly, if I create a symlink to this invalid location, the entry will immediately return and work normally.

Note: This issue does *not* occur on *most* installs.

What I can't figure out is:
How does this entry come about?
What system configuration or policy may alter CoreLocation's behavior?
Can this be removed or updated somehow?

(edit - fixed grammar errors)

Comment: The following Apple Community post shows a similar issue: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252922732

Comment: Did the user run your app first from a "random" location, and then later moved it into Applications to run it from there? - I.e. they have used it from the Downloads folder or something like that, and moved it later.

Comment: In a sense yes, we have a pkg installer since we create some LaunchAgents. We, at one point, moved our .app (not in the /Application directory, but a location where additional resources and code are located) thinking that the move was a benign change. The invalid location is the _previous_ location. The odd bit is that this entry normally doesn't exist in the DB.